# How to cross compile gcc for Intel Atom machine?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, intel

I've been trying to compile gcc on a Virtual Machine so I can use the binaries on another machine I have but keep running into errors all the time and trying to find answers. I would like to know if there is a set of instructions for me to compile the gcc library on an i7 machine but run the binaries on an Atom one. Specifically the Buffalo TeraStation TS-6VHL. Otherwise if there is a way to get gcc without compiling that would be great too - note that there is no package manager available.

```
# uname -a
Linux NAS 2.6.31.8-atom_d510 #2 SMP Wed Aug 21 08:50:32 JST 2013 x86_64 unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Linux on your machine is somewhat regular, maybe there is no need to cross-compile anything here, with some luck you can just copy everything from any general purpose Linux distribution that roughly fits the system on your machine, Atom is a normal Intel processor after all.  You should try a distribution where the kernel and glibc are the same or slightly older as compared to your machine. Start by copying the binary (gcc.exe), it will tell you what's missing.  The first issue will be glibc, the header files, the directory /usr/lib/gcc, binutils, and probably much more.  It will take a while and it will be messy, but maybe you want to give it a try.

Comment: So sorry for the very delayed reply. I hadnt seen your answer before. What I actually have is a Buffalo Terastation NAS with the Atom processor. Seems like this device is not very popular and it also seems like Buffalo stripped all the good stuff from their linux distribution. I have managed to get root access but anything I try to install fails and I have not been able to find gcc or any c compiler that works on it.